# Array becomes undefined after pushing an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array I define in the following way:

`var img_files = {};`

This works fine, and when I say `console.log(img_files)`, I get a fine response.

However, when i do the following:

```
        console.log(data.key);
        console.log(img_files);
        img_files.push({
            path: data.key
        });
        console.log(img_files);
```

I get:

```
811ab0b1-24c3-4274-b59c-5feb80e10130.jpg 
Object {} 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So after I push my object, I get an undefined of my array.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{}` is NOT an array. it's an object. `push` is undefined for objects. That's why the error is showing this.

`[]` is an array in javascript (and in almost every programming language).

```
var img_files = [];
```

Comment: Ah :) So what do I do instead to fix my problem? I am trying to add these objects to an array... EDIT: thanks